# Were there Yarchei Kallah in Judea during the Amoraim era?

Tags: amoroim

Did the Yarchei Kallah only happen in Babylonia during the Amoraim and Geonim era, or did Judea (Israel) also have them during the Amoraim era?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kallah#cite_ref-6) says: "_In the land of Israel there was no Kallah. [A. Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kallah#cite_note-6) claims that this cannot be asserted with certainty, but available historical records show that the Kallah was purely an institution practiced in Babylonia._"